# Allow only .csv files for nginx authentication

Tags: csv, nginx, server

I'm trying to allow only .csv files after /import/, but block the rest. Right now it's set up to allow any file type after /import/

```
location ^~ /import {
    auth_basic off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
location ^~ /import {
    if ($uri !~ \.csv$) { return 403; }
}
```

if you want HTTP 403 error for all other requests, or

```
location ^~ /import {
    if ($uri !~ \.csv$) { rewrite ^ /index.php last; }
}
```

if you want to redirect other requests to your `index.php`.